# Why is the cost for the Sort operator in this execution plan so high?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

[image: execution plan]

The **Sort** operator says its only got 100 rows to sort. How could that possibly be more expensive than reading 1.9 million rows? I must be reading this wrong or misunderstanding something.

Also, how is the **Estimated Number of Rows Per Execution** in the Sort operator only 100? If the **Index Seek** operator estimates the **Number of Rows Per Execution** to be 1.9 million, how does only 100 rows get piped over to the Sort operator?

Here is the query:

```
    DECLARE @PageIndex INT = 1000;
    DECLARE @PageCount INT  = 1000;

    SELECT  ID
    FROM    dbo.Table1
    WHERE DateCreated >= '2021-10-27'
            AND
        DateCreated < '2021-10-28'
    ORDER BY ID
        OFFSET @PageIndex * @PageCount ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageCount ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: The 100 is the **estimated** output rows due to the estimated effect of the `TOP` from the `OFFSET ... FETCH`. It needs to sort the entire 1.9 million rows it estimates as input before it outputs any.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, that makes sense. Thank you. Follow up question: why only 100 rows? Shouldn't it be 1000 since we are fetching 1000?

Comment: It doesn't sniff variables so will just use hardcoded guesses. The execution plan is compiled before the variables are even assigned a value.

Comment: The plan is optimized to accommodate any `@PageCount`, not just the specific one you happen to have specified here, and the guess is 100.

Comment: Side point: You may want to look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), which is far more efficient than Row Pagination which you are currently doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sort operator (as opposed to "Top N Sort") will sort the entirety of its input in its open method before returning any rows.

SQL Server estimates that the seek will output 1.9 million rows that go into the sort.

The costing is therefore for sorting 1.9 million rows.

You are doing

```
OFFSET 1000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

The actual output rows from the sort will be at least 1,001,000 ([maybe more in a parallel plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/inaccurate-actual-row-counts-in-parallel-plan)) and the `TOP` operator discards the first million for the offset and then stops requesting rows after it has received the 1000 to be returned.

The estimate of `100` is just a guess as SQL Server has no idea what the value of the variables will be at runtime when the plan is compiled.